# jQuery ajax is not redirecting for PHP twitter login

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, twitter

I am using [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) library for Twitter login. My ajax request is:

```
$('#twitterlogin').click(function(){
      alert('login');
      $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo site_url('socialauth/loginTwitter');?>",
              type: 'POST',
              success:function(data){
                alert(data);  
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                      console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
               }
        });
    });
```

**Console.log**

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
AJAX error: error :
```

After debugging it I found out ajax call is not redirecting flow to the twitter url with oauth key etc.
Same php code works fine if I call the same PHP url from submit button.
Is there something missing here?

Comment: are you sending any data along with it? or does site_url have the data tacked on.

Comment: code looked ok ,try to put base_url() instead of site_url().

Comment: I am not sending any data. Just want to hit the url.